# onClickListener for a button not working in a fragment

Tags: java, android

this is my code and I don't know why it is not listening for the button events
the below code is from fragment file

```
//  private Button button;
    LayoutInflater lf;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        lf=inflater;
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,
                container, false);
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.home_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent intent=new Intent(lf.getContext(),sunhan_activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at your code and you will get idea why the code is not working. Actually you are inflating layout 2 times, so last one will be executed and your first inflate  `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container, false);` will not be executed as you have not used it.

Simply change code like this:

```
//  private Button button;
LayoutInflater lf;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    lf=inflater;
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,
            container, false);
    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.home_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent=new Intent(lf.getContext(),sunhan_activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't have to declare extra variable for `LayoutInflater` because your `onCreateView()` already has one to use.
2. Don't call context from inflater again after removing, your fragment has it's own context. So replace `lf.getContext()` with `getContext()` inside intent. Since you are calling an activity from fragment use `getActivity()` instead of `getContext()`.
3. Don't return new `inflater` again at the end, you have previously assigned one before to `View`. So return the varibale you have declared from view.

replace this

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
```

with

```
return view;
```

Finally this is how it should look like:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.home_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), sunhan_activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```